# How to deal with WELD-001477 after JBoss EAP update to 7.2.1?

Tags: java, serialization, dependency-injection, jboss-eap-7

I'm currently testing the latest **JBoss EAP 7.2.1** compared to the previous 7.2.0 release. While 7.2.0 worked just fine for our large enterprise application the later 7.2.1 now throws many exceptions like this one during startup:

> **WELD-001477**: The bean Managed Bean [class package.SomeFacadeBean] with
>   qualifiers [@Any @Default] declares a passivating scope but has a(n)
>   Interceptor [class
>   com.arjuna.ats.jta.cdi.transactional.TransactionalInterceptorMandatory
>   intercepts @Transactional] with a non-passivation-capable dependency
>   com.arjuna.ats.jta.cdi.JNDIBean@6f5e65a8

These beans are declared like this:

```
@ConversationScoped
public class SomeFacadeBean implements SomeFacade, Serializable {

    // Simplified example...
    @Transactional
    public void someMethod(Object param) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I could solve this initial `WELD-001477` error in the EJB module by removing `@ConversationScoped` here – but than this very same error is thrown for all my UI beans in the WEB module which use `@Transactional` methods combined with `@ConversationScoped` for their classes.

And I can't really remove `@ConversationScoped` here – these are UI beans which need that scope.

```
@ConversationScoped
public class SomeBeanUI implements Serializable {

    // Simplified example...
    @Inject
    private SomeFacade facade;

    private Object anySerializable;

    @Transactional
    public void save() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

**So how do I solve this new problem with JBoss EAP 7.2.1?**

Comment: Reading after posting... and thinking: "maybe I should only remove `@ConversationScoped` and not `Serializable`..." #damn

Comment: It solves WELD-001413... but the initial problem remains. I'll update the post...

Comment: Since you're on JBoss EAP you could always open a support case for this https://access.redhat.com/support/cases/#/case/new. I'm not a CDI expert, but it does seem like a regression.

Comment: I've opened one... we'll see which comes first.

Comment: The support ticket also points at a possible regression. Submitted minimal deployable example.

Comment: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-11716

Comment: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBTM-3110

Comment: Looks like there is now an open JIRA for 7.2.x https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBEAP-16910. I'm guessing that's for you :)

Comment: EAP 7.2.2 has been released yesterday... and guess what? `WELD-001477` has not been fixed: "Suppressed: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.UnserializableDependencyException: WELD-001477: The bean Managed Bean [class my.package.xyz.ErrorsUI] with qualifiers [@Default @Any @Named] declares a passivating scope but has a(n) Interceptor [class com.arjuna.ats.jta.cdi.transactional.TransactionalInterceptorRequired intercepts @Transactional] with a non-passivation-capable dependency com.arjuna.ats.jta.cdi.JNDIBean@314148db" – did they forget about that?

Comment: It looks like it will be fixed in 7.2.3 according to the JIRA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the completeness... this regression has been fixed with EAP 7.2.3.